# Is there such a thing as "Client Side" VBScript in web development?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I got into a a discussion with a co-worker today regarding client side scripts.  JavaScript is the only client side scripting language I have used (and the only one i know of), but she seemed to think that you could have VBScript on the client side as well.  Is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for Internet Explorer:

```
<script language="vbscript">
    MsgBox ("Your entry was valid.")
</script>
```

Link:
    http://www.asp101.com/tips/index.asp?id=35

You can also have client-side c#.

Comment: Also be aware that VBScript only works in IE. http://w3schools.com/vbscript/default.asp

Comment: And I'd like to add that VBScript only works in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Someone should mention that VBScript won't work in Firefox or Chrome. Only IE.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that VBScript was limited to a specific browser. Is that true? And which one is it?

Comment: It's IE (sorry it took me so long)